# How to get a variable defined in build.gradle inside test files in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing

I am writing unit tests for my current android application. And I am using the app's version code in some APIs. This version code is defined in `build.gradle` file.(A gradle variable). Now is there a way to access this information in the test code? I am using `JUNIT` and `Mockito` for my testing. Or is it entirely wrong to use gradle variables in testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` not working for you?

Comment: yes it is working. Thanks. I didn't know about that